# I am trying to display two live video screens as one live screen "layered" "not side by side"

Tags: asp.net

I have a live screen on my computer from a video camera, and a live screen on my computer from a spectrum scope, see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RFPojOo-hI4  for a video of this display.

I want to layer the top portion of the scope screen "the part with spikes, not vertical bars"
onto a screen with the live video camera screen, so that on one screen a live video is shown with the frequency wavelength moving across it "in a park showing a bench with the frequency moving across it"

and so that on another window, "i assume by making each window smaller i can display two screens side by side"
i can show the entire scope display.

What is the name of a computer program that allows me to do this?

If there are none, what is the name of a program that allws me to develop my own program to do this?

it should be simple, as i am just trying to display two feeds "inputs" on one screen

Answer (score 0):

With compiz windowmanager (linux) you can just move the windows on top of each other and increase the transparancy for the topmost window. Only one windo will have the focus, of course.

The opacity plugin has a default key/mouse shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ScrollWheel</kbd>